# Я говорил про 2- и 3-слойный коврик

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я говорил про 2- и 3-слойный коврик.

> Я говорил про 2-х и 3-слойный коврик.

> Я говорил про 2-х и 3-х слойный коврик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты *2-х слойный* и *3-х слойный* совсем уж некорректны.

Корректно использовать только *висячий дефис*:

***Я говорил про 2- и 3-слойный коврик***.

«Грамота.ру»:

[image]